# Convert .opus to .wav in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio, wav, opus

I want to classify audio clip files using Tensorflow. But my audio files are in `.opus` format. From my research I need them to be in `.wav` format.

Therefore, I have to convert them. I would like to do this in Python, because I am working in a Jupyter notebook. I want to do this for hundreds of files.

All [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231582/how-to-convert-opus-file-into-wav-file#:%7E:text=ffmpeg%20or%20even%20vlc%20can%20do%20it.) so far was [this command line approach](https://superuser.com/questions/1327921/ffmpeg-convert-webm-opus-to-wav-or-flac-in-single-step). My trouble with it, is that it would be too slow to perform on one file at a time. I want a method that can loop through hundreds of files in several directories and convert them all.

Answer (score 1):

One can use this in Python:

```py
opus_path = 'something.opus'
wav_path = 'something.wav'
os.system(f'ffmpeg -i "{opus_path}" -vn "{wav_path}"')
```

This can obviously be applied in a loop if you want:

```py
for opus_path,wav_path in zip(opus_paths,wav_paths):
    os.system(f'ffmpeg -i "{opus_path}" -vn "{wav_path}"')
```